# How does home screen work in Kodi(XBMC)?

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I was wondering how the scrolling through options feature works in kodi..
[image]

Here, I can only scroll through Videos, Music, Programs etc options when the mouse pointer is near the bar, if the mouse pointer is in any other part if the screen, scrolling through mouse wheel won't work. I want to add a similar button(i.e activated by wheel when ponter is in that region) to another part of kodi(full screen video). Can anyone tell me how I can do this or where the config files for home screen are located??

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS. You must locate the skin folder (the default one is `skin.confluence`) and look for the `720p` folder. There you will find `Home.xml` which is the file than contains the contents seen on the home screen.

You can add a new `item` under the `content` group of `<control type="fixedlist" id="9000">`